# Make Info window Marker Google Maps Always Appear Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps

i have info window that shows after tapped, but how to make it always appear? Without user tap on the marker. I'm using Google Maps.

here's my code :

```
    mapView.delegate = self
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: coordinate.lat, longitude: coordinate.long, zoom: 20)
    mapView.animate(to: camera)

    for state in states {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(state.lat, state.long)
        print(marker.position)
        marker.title = "Country"
        marker.snippet = "Places"
        marker.map = mapView
        mapView.selectedMarker = marker
        marker.map = mapView

    }
```

thanks before

Answer (score 1):

**First we need to Add a marker.**

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10, longitude: 10)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.title = "Hello World"
marker.map = mapView
```

**We can Customize the marker image by this:-**

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.127)
let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
london.title = "London"
london.icon = UIImage(named: "house")
london.map = mapView
//To change the Marker Opacity use below
marker.opacity = 0.6
```

**To Rotate a marker:-**

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.127)
let degrees = 90.0
let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
london.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
london.rotation = degrees
london.map = mapView
```

**And to Add an info window:-**

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.127)
let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
london.title = "London"
london.snippet = "Population: 8,174,100"
london.map = mapView
```

**To Set an info window to refresh automatically**

```
marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true
```

**To Change the position of an info window**

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.127)
let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
london.title = "London"
london.snippet = "Population: 8,174,100"
london.infoWindowAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
london.icon = UIImage(named: "house")
london.map = mapView
```

For more details you can go [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#add_an_info_window)

Answer (score 0):

try to move `mapView.selectedMarker = marker` to delegate function `mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool` function